# Android: Programmatically calculate Listview Font Metrics

Tags: android, fontmetrics

I have a String and I need to truncate the string such that it fits on one line in a ListView.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that in the XML of your list item row file.

These are the attributes you need to play with on your TextView;

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLength="someLengthofCharacters(int)"
android:ellipsize="end"  //if you want an ellipse to be appended to the end of your String
```

EDIT: Try this approach to set the max character length of your TextView programmatically

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
int maxLength = 10;
InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
tv.setFilters(fArray)
```

and set single line to true by using

```
TextView.setSingleLine or TextView.setLines(1)
```

Comment: After thought: Are you using a custom listview and adapter?